# delimiter size in cases environment

Tags: delimiters, cases

How can I change delimiter (brace) size in cases environment (for piece-wise function)?

```
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases}

\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: You have to put something inside the `cases` environment to make it expand. Surely you can show the piece-wise function, otherwise it's difficult to assess what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: May be provide an image illustrating what you want? For example you can affect the vertical space between the cases with `\\[<length>]`.

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the brace (vertical and/or horizontal) are of prime concern, an alternative to the `cases` environment is given below.  In this MWE, the stacked cases are composed of a `\Vectorstack` (`stackengine` package) in which the argument is set in math mode on equally spaced lines set about the math axis.  The brace is produced by the `scalerel` package, and is merely a width-limited vertical scale of a glyph, in this case the left brace `{`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\centering
Vertical height of brace matches target stack:
\[ f(x) =
  \scalerel[2ex]{\{}{\Vectorstack{a\\b\\c}}
\]
\[ f(x) =
  \scalerel[2ex]{\{}{\Vectorstack{a\\b\\c\\d}}
\]
Vertical height of stack can be extended beyond stack height:
\[ f(x) =
  \scalerel[2ex]{\{}{\addstackgap[3pt]{\Vectorstack{a\\b\\c\\d}}}
\]
Maximum horizontal width of brace set by optional parameter:
\[ f(x) =
  \scalerel[3ex]{\{}{\Vectorstack{a\\b\\c\\d}}
\]
\[ f(x) =
  \scalerel[4ex]{\{}{\Vectorstack{a\\b\\c\\d}}
\]
\[ f(x) =
  \scalerel[1ex]{\{}{\Vectorstack{a\\b\\c\\d}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is just a demonstration of the ability to manipulate the brace.  For a real problem, there may be other considerations... If the vertical separation between "cases" needs to be increased, `\setstackgap{L}{length}` prior to the stack can accomplish that, for example.  See the package documentations for details.  Your mileage may vary.